# Trying to Assign Pointer out of a struct to a two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

have an assignment where I should use the following struct:

```
typedef struct natset{
        unsigned long min;
        unsigned int size;
        unsigned char* bits;
}natset_t;
```

Now I have to assign that pointer to the following two-dimensional array of unsigned chars:

```
unsigned char bArrayRoll[7][byteNum];
```

Which I have tried doing like so:

```
unsigned long min = 20;
unsigned int size = 20;
unsigned char bArrayRoll[7][byteNum];

natset_t newNatset;
newNatset.min = min;
newNatset.size = size;
newNatset.bits = &bArrayRoll;
```

Variations of that newNatset.bits which I have tried include:

```
newNatset.bits = bArrayRoll;
newNatset.bits* = &bArrayRoll;
```

However, the compiler either returns "Assignment from incompatible pointer type" or "Initialization from incompatible pointer type".

How can I assign the bits pointer to this array correctly?

Comment: Well, as it seems, you cannot and even if you would, it would not be a right thing to do. What are you upto?

Comment: @coderredoc well, looking at `Now I have to assign that pointer to the following two-dimensional array of unsigned chars:`, i still stand by my comment. :)

Comment: @coderredoc that is what I was trying to ask.. seems like x-y problem to me.

Comment: @SouravGhosh.: I updated my answer...I guess I am going in right direction guiding OP towards right solution. But yes surely seems like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
newNatset.bits* = &bArrayRoll;
```

You are trying to multiply `newNatset.bits` with the address of `bArrayRoll`, this is undefined behavior.

```
newNatset.bits = bArrayRoll;
```

This one here is trying to assign `unsigned char (*)[byteNum]` to `unsigned char*` which is again something about which compiler complained. Types are incompatible clearly.

Correct one would be (correct one as per the compiler)

```
newNatset.bits = bArrayRoll[0];
```

#### wouldn't it have to be: newNatset.bits = bArrayRoll[0][0]?

This is once again a type incompatible assignment. You are assigning `unsigned char` to `unsigned char*`. You can do this though,

```
newNatset.bits = &bArrayRoll[0][0];
```

#### Trying to Assign Pointer out of a struct to a two-dimensional array? (The thing you wanted).

Then you need to do this,

```
  unsigned char (*p)[byteNum] = bArrayRoll;
```

but in the structure you have declared `bits` to be of type `unsigned char*` not of type `unsigned char (*)[byteNum]`.

Well if you didn't understand what happened when we assigned in the last case and how did the types match - then here is the key idea.

The 2d array decays into the pointer to the first element - which is a single dimensional array of `byteNum` unsigned characters. Now we are assigning it to `p` which is again

```
unsigned char (*)[byteNum]
               ^ ^
               1 2
\-----------/ 
        3

Pointer to (1) an array of bytenum (2) unsigned characters (3).
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

but wouldn't it have to be: 

newNatset.bits = bArrayRoll[0][0];

?

Comment: @helplesslybadatcoding.: Updated answer with your question